# How to enable a windows 2008 R2 server to support for TLS 1.2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tls1.2

How to enable a windows 2008 R2 server to support for TLS 1.2? I am getting required output on my machine but not after deploying on server

I have already changed the .net framework to 4.6.1 and made the following changes in regedit:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: I maybe have the very same problem - right now I can only say that I got encryption issues on Windows Server 2008 and not on many other machines. Did you fix it? Also, I fount https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows-server-2008-sp2-windows-embedded-posready-2009-and-windows-embedded-standard-2009-b6ab553a-fa8f-3f5e-287c-e752eb3ce5f4 . Havent applied it yet though.

Comment: Yes I did, you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153734/2944950