# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in COM object

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, asp-classic

We're using a COM object (called from a Classic ASP web application) to do a webservice call. Recently the webservice disabled TLS1.0. We've updated the COM object to .NET 4.6.2 and added the following code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications ' This function returns true
```

Then a SOAP request is made using a custom certificate (issued by the webservice company) using a `X509Certificate2` object.
When running in a console application everything works fine. However, when the DLL is registered and called from Classic ASP the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

That's all unfortunately. Things we tried:

- Setting `KeepAlive` to `True` in the request
- Changing the local group policy "Allow local activation security check exemptions" to Enabled

Any ideas?

Comment: It means you're not running in the same environment in the console mode vs the asp classic mode. The framework runtime in your asp classic mode is probably too old.

Comment: See this post.  Your solution work for 4.5 and higher.  Try this solution (for 4.0).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0

Comment: @DanielBlais I downgraded to 4.0, same problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier The original DLL was built for .NET 2.0, so I think you're right