# Upgrading application to TLS1.2 from SSL requires code change in Application Server and any change in DB Server?

Tags: vb.net

My one of the applications is built on VB .NET 4.0 but the Application & Database Servers contains .NET framework 4.7.2.

I need to upgrade my application to support TLS1.2 from SSL.

As per the link 
[TLS 1.2 in .NET Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0/53046038#53046038), do I need to add the below code in Global.asax file or not? as my application built on .NET 4.0.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
```

If I have to add the code, then do I need to change anything in the DB server (currently accepts SSL requests) to accept this TLS12 request? and if my application use SOAP call (WCF), then do I need to add the above code in the WCF application as well?

Comment: The above code worked for me in VB.Net (keeping the project in framework 4.0).  Also seem to need the line `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True`

Answer (score 0):

See official TLS 1.2 guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

It would be best to retarget (rebuild) your app against higher .NET Framework.