# How to use TLS 1.2 from powershell on windows 7 / 64bits

Tags: powershell, tls1.2

I am trying to solve the following issue:

> Exception setting "SecurityProtocol": "Cannot convert value "tls13,
>   tls12, tls11, tls" to type "System.Net.SecurityProtocolType" due to
>   invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration
>   values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Ssl3,
>   Tls"."

Here is my system info (windows 7/64bits):

[image]

Powershell version is:

```
PS > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8789
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

I did follow instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34009938/136285). This is equivalent to:

```
# set strong cryptography on 64 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

And I could verify that I have:

[image: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]

However it stills fails for me (using a newly created powershell window):

```
PS > [enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType])
Ssl3
Tls
```

For reference:

[image]

Comment: what version of powershell are you using? ///// also, PLEASE ... DO NOT post pictures of code, errors, or sample data. why would anyone want to help you when you force them to squint/zoom in to read the text _that you already have as text?_. ///// why force your would-be helpers to type in your code _that you already have type in_ just to test your code?

Comment: The new `SecurityProtocolType` values only exist in .NET 4.5 and up; you're apparently still on .NET 4.0. This is irrespective of whether the OS supports the newer TLS. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33761919/4137916).

Comment: Note that no configuration setting whatsoever will change the tags present in the enum, as this is strictly dependent on the loaded .NET framework. PowerShell 2.0 can be [coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279372/4137916) to use a more recent version of .NET, though a more suitable solution is to just [upgrade it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616). See also the previous question I linked for answers on how to use the enum value even if your version of .NET doesn't support it; you can cast the numeric value, since it's passed directly down to the Schannel API.