# How to work download github release in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, github

I tried downloading the github file release from vb with this code

Short code

```
Dim DataDownload As String = "https://github.com/ianpwk/FindMyWaifu/releases/download/0.0.0.20/FindMyWaifuPortable.zip"
```

[Full Code in Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XThFCMMv)

Showing error "**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL / TLS secure channel.**"

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: net. version 4.0

Comment: I'm afraid you've got a problem then. GitHub uses TLS version 1.2 (HTTPS), but .NET Framework 4.0 only supports up to TLS 1.0. There are workarounds to enable TLS 1.2 in .NET 4.0, but they require you to have at least .NET 4.5 installed on the target machine so if that is not an option I'm afraid you have to look for a third-party library that supports TLS 1.2.

Comment: If, however, you are okay with requiring the target machine to have at least .NET 4.5 installed (most PCs already have this nowadays), you can find mentioned workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018682 - Add that line somewhere in your code (preferably at startup) before you make your first connection.