# C# WEB API project TLS 1.2 setup in IIS express

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6

I have a WEB API project running .net 4.6.1 that I want to get TLS 1.2 working on localhost in IIS express first, and then once I get that setup correctly, I want to deploy it to our dev server running IIS 7.5 on server 2008 R2 and have TLS setup there as well.

I already have this in the web config from reading other posts

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
```

I want to go the self signed route for now even though I know Chrome will warn its unsafe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TLS 1.2 in .NET Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0)