# Localhost uses unsupported protocol

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, browser

I am trying to run an Asp.net Core application using Visual Studio 2019 in Chrome browser but i'm getting the following error:

> "This site can’t provide a secure connection
> localhost uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH Unsupported protocol The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite."

I tried
repairing IIS Express 10,
clearing browser data and certificates cache,
deleting .vs folder,

But My .NET Core web apps are not working in Chrome.
How to solve this??

Comment: I am not familiar with IIES express 10 but check to see which TLS protocol is enabled .. Make sure to enable TLS v1.2 and higher

Comment: Check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0 it might help

Comment: I think you may try to [delete the self-signed certification](https://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-localhost-self-signed-ssl-certificate-expired-warning-browser-fix/) and add a new one when running your application again. And I also agree with Yan's idea to check the [TLS version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this URL in your Chrome browser to turn this flag on and then relaunch Chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Comment: It seems like he is having issues with the set TLS version, making it insecure would not help around that.

Comment: Seems he is using it in his local for development so thats why I said that.