# Sending email via Outlook365 from VB6/VB.net 4.0 application

Tags: winforms, vb6, office365, .net-4.0, tls1.2

We currently have a legacy VB6/VB.Net 4.0 application (we're stuck with those because of a need to support XP unfortunately), and one of its functions is to send out email. It currently works with various of our clients SMTP servers just fine using the Ostrosoft SMTP component. However is doesn't work with Office365 as that now requires the use of TLS1.2 with 'StartTLS', which the Ostrosoft component doesn't support.

I've tried various things in .Net, but nothing seems to work.

e.g.:

```
        Try
            Using SMTPMailServer As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
                Using MailMessage As Net.Mail.MailMessage = New Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                    SMTPMailServer.Port = 587
                    SMTPMailServer.Host = "smtp.office365.com"
                    SMTPMailServer.EnableSsl = True
                    SMTPMailServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                    SMTPMailServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                    SMTPMailServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("**id**", "**password**")

                    MailMessage.From = New MailAddress(FromAddress)
                    MailMessage.To.Add(ToAddress)

                    MailMessage.Subject = $"Test Email {DateTime.Now}"
                    MailMessage.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail using Method 1"

                    SMTPMailServer.Send(MailMessage)
                End Using

                MsgBox("Mail sent")
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox($"Error : {ex.Message}")
        End Try
```

This results in the following error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks.

Note, I've tried setting the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to 3072, no change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TLS 1.2 in .NET Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: @GSerg I had seen that post, and unfortunately it does not. That post seems to be talking about a WebForms app, where this in WinForms. However, I've tried to set the mentioned registry keys and the ServicePointManager with no difference.

Comment: It makes no difference that it's winforms, you need [one code line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0#comment74062551_33768421) that you can put anywhere. Although I'm realizing it's not going to work for you because you don't actually have 4.5 installed that is required for it to work.

Comment: If you're potentially willing to invest in a new library, have a look at [SocketTools](https://sockettools.com/)

Comment: A workaround would be to save the mail info to a network drive, and have some process running on a newer OS that scans the folder, and handles sending the mail. Or another idea that might work is setup an internal SMTP (e.g. `SMTPMailServer.Host = "192.168.x.y";`) that relays the emails to smtp.office365.com, but I haven't done that before.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. We've had to work around the problem by using a commercial email server that we can access via SMTP. It's not ideal, but it fulfils the immediate customer requirement. It's still something we'll need to address in a future release, so keep any suggestions coming.

Comment: @Slugsie If you search `https://www.google.com/search?q=windowsxp+tls1.2` there are several suggestions. One of them looked promising `https://msfn.org/board/topic/178092-enable-tls-11-and-12-in-windows-xp-correctly/` answer by Mathwiz. Maybe after installing KB4019276, the `(SecurityProtocolType)3072;` hack might work. Probably wise to test this on a spare XP machine, especially if doing the regedits.

Comment: @Slugsie It may turn out that you need to change the settings in IE8. It could be that the TLS setting in IE8 dictates the TLS setting for the entire OS. Just a guess.

Comment: For XP you cannot use built-in Schannel for TLS 1.2 (it's not supported) so you have to use other TLS library. Take a look at [this thread](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?894683-RESOLVED-VB6-QUESTION-CDO-Email-Guide-and-STARTTLS) for a STARTTLS proxy using custom TLS 1.2  implementation (and TLS 1.3) for VB6.